# How can I change/replace some functions with some other functions within a package?

Tags: r

I am trying to make some changes or replace some functions with other ones within the R package `rodd`. I have downloaded and extracted the source codes. They are in different files and some of them need editing. How can I do it in a proper way?

I searched on the internet. I only found cases who need one single change in a function within a package. But in my case, the package `rodd` needs some more changes and also replacing some functions with the original ones. I also need to mention that I need to make a 2 dimensional (for the control variable X) version of the package. So I am still not sure which changes fit my needs and each time I need to make some changes and see which changes solve the problem. I also need to have both the actual version and the edited version of the package. 
Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

```
tpopt(x, ...)
```

I would also mention I need to make some changes in the procedure (other functions) which result in the function `tpopt`, not the function `tpopt` itself.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have to make some substantial changes, so wouldn't the easiest solution be to copy the source files, implement your changes and create an alternative `rodd2`-package for local use?